# How to get Class Method on Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello I try to get all Methods on a Class Controller on Laravel but I was failed.
I use get_class_methods function to get class methods.

Here is my ConfigController codes:

```php
use Modules\Order\Http\Controllers\V1\Web\OrderController;
class ConfigController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $methods = get_class_methods(new OrderController::class);
        dd($methods);
    }
}
```

After executing the code the result is:

```php
Class "Modules\Order\Http\Controllers\V1\Web\OrderController" not found
```

And I'm sure that that class exists on that namespace because I have already called it on route.

How to do that on the right way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reflection yet? My example below:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionMethod($className, $methodName);
$parameter = $reflection->getParameters();
foreach ($parameter as $param) {
    echo $parameter->getName();
    echo $parameter->isOptional();
}
```

Comment: How to call ReflectionMethod class on Laravel?

Comment: I got this error:
Class "Modules\Config\Http\Controllers\V1\Web\ReflectionMethod" not found

Comment: I think you forget to add "use ReflectionMethod;" at the top of your code.

Comment: Ya, sometimes the class is hide under another class. I don't know the exact namespece of the class.

Comment: I don't know the result still the same:
Class "Modules\Order\Http\Controllers\V1\Web\OrderController" not found

Comment: Are you sure that your class exists? have you debugged it yet?

Comment: I've used it on another file, and it working fine.

Comment: I thought you missed some points, please double-check.

Comment: Yes, actually my class name is OrdersController not OrderController, I miss s on the Class name, thank you for your help. I solved it.

Comment: Sure, Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer, I just miss s on the method name:

```php
use ReflectionClass;
...
$reflection = new ReflectionClass(OrdersController);
dd($reflection);
...
```